# How to return a promise from a boolean check inline?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm new to promise syntax. Previously I had code like this, and requests would return a zipfile:

```
// in first file
exports.requireSubscription = function(req) {
    if (feature_is_available) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    else {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("You need to upgrade your account to access this feature."));
    }
};

//from the npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver
const archiver = require("archiver");
utils.requireSubscription(req)
  .then(() => getPage(req, res, "view"))
  .then(function(page) {
    const zip = archiver.create("zip", {});
    // ...
    zip.finalize();
  }).catch(utils.fail(req, res));
```

Now I want to remove the separate function for `requireSubscription`, and use a single file with a check inline.

I've tried this:

```
if (feature_is_available) {
  getPage(req, res, "view"))
    .then(function(page) {
      const zip = archiver.create("zip", {}); 
      // ...
      zip.finalize();
    });
} else {
  utils.fail(req, res);
}
```

However, the request is hanging. I think perhaps I'm not returning a promise when I should be returning one - previously `requireSubscription` returned a promise, now my inline check does not.

How can I rewrite this to return the right thing?

Update: here is the `utils.fail` function:

```
exports.fail = function(req, res) {
    return function(error) {
        if (error instanceof acl.PermissionDeniedError) {
            return res.status(403).render("error_nothing_here.html", { user: req.user, error: error });
        }
        else if (error instanceof errors.NotFoundError) {
            return res.status(404).render("error_nothing_here.html", { user: req.user, error: error });
        }
        res.status(500).render("internal_error.html", { "error": error });
    };
};
```

Comment: `() => () {` <--- what's this?

Comment: The code as posted is syntactically incorrect. It's hard to tell what you really meant.

Comment: We need a [mcve]. The code looks ok, but without details as to what `archiver` is and does it's hard to say why "it hangs"

Comment: One thought, what is and what sets `feature_is_available`?

Comment: `How can I rewrite this to return the right thing?` a `return`  statement would help, but since your original "2nd file" code doesn't return anything, it's hard to say - however, as mentioned, neither versions of your code is syntactically correct

Comment: Please also provide the `utils.fail` function, does it return a function or does it directly end the request when called?

Comment: Sorry. I've fixed the syntax, and clarified [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver).

Comment: It's npm [archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver).

Comment: Yes, I saw your comment, the problem is, without knowing the npm package `'archiver'` could be anything. Anyway, I've added into your code

Comment: If it helps, it's the failure path that's hanging, so I think it's that part that's not returning correctly.

Comment: Maybe this isn't all the code in question but it looks like there's an extra parenthesis before the first ".then". I would make sure whatever that corresponds to is actually returning a promise so it would be then-able. If it even belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator to inline the body of the function as a single expression:

```
(feature_is_available
  ? Promise.resolve()
  : Promise.reject(new Error("You need to upgrade your account to access this feature."))
).then(() =>
  getPage(req, res, "view")
).then(page => {
  const zip = archiver.create("zip", {});
  // ...
  zip.finalize();
}).catch(utils.fail(req, res));
```

The problem with your version that the promise chain had no `catch` handler attached, and that you didn't call the function that was created by `fail()` in the `else` branch. You would need to write

```
if (feature_is_available) {
  getPage(req, res, "view"))
  .then(page => {
    const zip = archiver.create("zip", {}); 
    // ...
    zip.finalize();
  })
  .catch(utils.fail(req, res));
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
} else {
  utils.fail(req, res)(new Error("You need to upgrade your account to access this feature."));
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```